# $q.all not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating project using angularjs. I have problem while calling api's with $q.all.Here is my code:

```
$q.all({
                getCustomerInfo: promocodeService.getCustomerInfo(),
                assCustomerPromoCode: promocodeService.assCustomerPromoCode(),
                getPromocodes:promocodeService.getPromocodes(),
                getAllCurrencies:promocodeService.getAllCurrencies(),
            }).then(function(resolved) {

// here not comes when one of the api is failed

                $rootScope.customerInfo = resolved.getCustomerInfo;
                $scope.assPromoCode = resolved.assCustomerPromoCode;
                $scope.promoCodes = resolved.getPromocodes;
                $scope.getAllCurrencies = resolved.getAllCurrencies;

                });
```

My problem is when one of the api fails it does not come into the resolved state.

Comment: When one of the api's fails, it will come into the catch function. You should define a `.catch(function(error) { //error handling })` method

Comment: what do you expect/want to happen when one of the api's fails? Fallback to some default-value? Or what else?

Comment: if one api fails it does not show the data of other api's also, i want to show the data of api's in case of if api fails

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavour.  `all` is designed to execute when they all succeed.

Some alternatives you could try, depending on your requirements:

```
$q.all({
    //...
}).then(function(resolved) {
    //...
}).catch(function() {
    //Do something?
}).finally(function() {
    //Do something?
})
```